# How to print all records selected using a GridClientSelectColumn in multiple pages of radgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a rad grid with paging enabled.I select all rows in multiple pages using a GridClientSelectColumn. When I click on print button it prints only the records which are displayed in first page,not all records selected in multiple pages. How to fix it.

This is how i selected all checkboxes in multiple pages.

```
            var selected = {};
            function radGridWarehouseUtility_RowSelected(sender, args) {
                var LID = args.getDataKeyValue("LID");
                if (!selected[LID]) {
                    selected[LID] = true;
                }
            }

            function radGridWarehouseUtility_RowDeselected(sender, args) {
                var LID = args.getDataKeyValue("LID");
                if (selected[LID]) {
                    selected[LID] = null;
                }
            }

           function pageLoad() {
               var dataItems = $find('<%=radGridWarehouseUtility.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
               for (var i = 0, j = dataItems.length; i < j; i++) {
                   var item = dataItems[i];
                   if (selected[item.getDataKeyValue("LID")]) {
                       item.set_selected(true);
                   }
               }
           }
                    <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                        <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="radGridWarehouseUtility_RowSelected"
                            OnRowDeselected="radGridWarehouseUtility_RowDeselected" />
                    </ClientSettings>

     <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="Select" />  // Use for for selecting all checkboxes.
```

code behind...

```
  Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

     For Each item As GridDataItem In radGridWarehouseUtility.SelectedItems
        Dim item1 As GridDataItem = item
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox
        chkBox = DirectCast(item1.Item("Select").Controls(0), CheckBox)

        If chkBox.Enabled Then
            Dim lid As String
            lid = CType(radGridWarehouseUtility.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues(item.ItemIndex)("LID"), String)
            qryParams = qryParams & lid & ","
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Plz reply....

Thanks in advance.